# Why does Windows have Native API?

Tags: operating-system

Why does modern os implement a kind of hirarchy of calling internal functions?
like in windows when you call ReadFile function you acually call to NtReadFile.
Why doesnt windows call directly into NtReadFile?

What will happen if the os will call into internal function directly?

Comment: Up-voted because I don't think it is a bad question. It might belong on Programmers, though.

Answer (score 3):

The current version of Windows is based on [Windows NT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT), which was started in 1989. Back then they didn't know what OS/API would be popular so they designed Windows NT to have a generic native API (`NtReadFile`) and multiple subsystems (Windows, POSIX, OS/2) that would translate calls into that native API.

In 1989 Windows was not popular, and the designers intended that [OS/2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS/2) would be the primary subsystem. It was only after Microsoft left the OS/2 partnership with IBM and [Windows 3.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_3.0) came out in 1990 and became very popular that they decided to make a Windows subsystem. As a result, the Win32 subsystem was created to translate calls like `ReadFile` into `NtReadFile`.

Answer (score 2):

Decoupling and legacy. You have to remember that NT was originally designed as a [microkernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microkernel) that would support multiple APIs on top of it, with the default API of course being the already established WIN32 API.

If you call `NtReadFile` directly you are no longer using the WIN32 API.